# Suitable options for git log -p if worried about evil merges

Tags: git, merge, git-log

I'm worried that a given branch I'm looking at may have some evil merges in it. What options should I add to `git log -p` to be more verbose for diffs displayed for merge commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of

```
git log -p -c
```

or

```
#(note: two dashes, then two "c"s)
git log -p --cc
```

seem to be a good option.

From the section "Diff Formatting" of documentation on [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

> Listed below are options that control the formatting of diff output. Some of them are specific to `git-rev-list[1]`, however other diff options may be given. See `git-diff-files[1]` for more options.
>
> `-c`
>
> With this option, diff output for a merge commit shows the differences from each of the parents to the merge result simultaneously instead of showing pairwise diff between a parent and the result one at a time. Furthermore, it lists only files which were modified from all parents.
>
> `--cc`
>
> This flag implies the `-c` option and further compresses the patch output by omitting uninteresting hunks whose contents in the parents have only two variants and the merge result picks one of them without modification.

it seems `--cc` is designed to show the evil merges, and hide the non-evil merges.